# Expected value of distinct balls

Tags: combinatorics

My friend posed me the following question:

> We have a bowl with 70 balls, 7 colors, and 10 balls in each color.
>
> You draw 20 balls simultaneously from the bowl. What is the expected number of distinct colors?

I tried working out this problem for $2$, and $3$ colours the rest seemed difficult.

**2:** Here we need all the balls from 2 distinct colours. This can be done in $7P2 = 7 \cdot 6$ ways.

**3: ** For three balls this got more interesting we have the restraints $i + j + k = 20$, $i \in [1,10]$, $j = [1,10]$, $k \in [1,10]$. Also we have $i + j \geq 10$. This gives me

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{10} \left( \sum_{j = \min(10-i,1)}^{9} 1\right) = 54
$$
Multiplying this with the number of ways to pick $3$ colors from $7$ I get
$$
P(\text{3 distinct colors}) = 54\cdot (7\text{Pn} 3) = 11340
$$

I tried to solve this problem numerically, and it seems that the expected number of different balls is about
$$
E(b) \approx 6.818835818835818685101912706159055233001708984375
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each colour has probability

$$
1-\frac{\binom{60}{20}}{\binom{70}{20}}
$$

of being drawn, so by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) the expected number of colours drawn is

$$
7\left(1-\frac{\binom{60}{20}}{\binom{70}{20}}\right)=\frac{763700091}{112000148}\approx6.81874\;.
$$